# Unable to click an element with R Selenium

Tags: r, click, element, rselenium

I can't click on an item, that displays next results, with RSelenium. I think it's a selector problem, but I tried a lot of things (xpath and CSS), without success. Thanks for your help!Below, the link and the code concerned.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(RSelenium)
url<-"https://www.sncf.com/fr/gares/Abbaretz/OCE87481614/departs-arrivees/gl/departs"
remDr$navigate(url)
Bouton<-remDr$findElement(using='css selector',".search-filter-results-load-more-btn")
Bouton$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(3)
page_source<-remDr$getPageSource()
URL<-read_html(page_source[[1]])
Horaire<-html_text(html_nodes(URL,".time"))
Destination<-str_sub(html_text(html_nodes(URL,".timetables-destination")),6)
NoTrain<-html_text(html_nodes(URL,".timetables-train-id"))
HDN1<-cbind(NomGare,Horaire,Destination,NoTrain)
```

Comment: Was does without success entail? Was there an error message? Is so, what was it?

Comment: What you want scrape? Refer https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html